# Is there a difference between str function and percent operator in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

When converting an object to a string in python, I saw two different idioms:

A: `mystring = str(obj)`

B: `mystring = "%s" % obj`

Is there a difference between those two? (Reading the Python docs, I would suspect no, because the latter case would implicitly call `str(obj)` to convert `obj` to a string.

If yes, when should I use which?

If no, which one should I prefer in "good" python code? (From the python philosophy "explicit over implicit", A would be considered the better one?)

Comment: I would go for the first one but very good question (+1) - I am sure some professional pythonistas will be very willing to answer :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The second version does more work.

The `%s` operator calls `str()` on the value it interpolates, but it also has to parse the template string first to find the placeholder in the first place.

Unless your template string contains *more text*, there is no point in asking Python to spend more cycles on the `"%s" % obj` expression.

However, paradoxically, the `str()` conversion is, in practice, slower as looking up the name `str()` and pushing the stack to call the function takes more time than the string parsing:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit('str(obj)', 'obj = 4.524')
0.32349491119384766
>>> timeit('"%s" % obj', 'obj = 4.524')
0.27424097061157227
```

You can recover most of that difference by binding `str` to a local name first:

```
>>> timeit('_str(obj)', 'obj = 4.524; _str = str')
0.28351712226867676
```

To most Python developers, using the string templating option is going to be confusing as `str()` is far more straightforward. Stick to the function unless you have a critical section that does a lot of string conversions.

Comment: I would not have expected those numbers. Thanks for the timeit results

Comment: Thank you for the precise and fast answer ;)

Comment: Yes, but you could just write `"%s" % (obj,)`.